# How does continue statement work in function?

Tags: python

i am building scientific calculator. After performing the operation it ask do u want to go back in main menu or Exit

```
def Again():
    x=input ("Go back to main menu(Y/N)")
    if (x=='Y') or (x=='y'):
        continue
    else:
        break
```

when user press y it go back to main menu otherwise exit

Comment: It doesn't. `break` and `continue` are only relevant inside loops.

Answer (score 1):

You can`t use `break` and `continue` in function, read [tutorial](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/break-continue)

instead, you can use check in your main loop, and your function must return `True` or `False`

```
def Again():
    x=input ("Go back to main menu(Y/N)")
    if (x=='Y') or (x=='y'):
        return True
    else:
        return False

while True:  # your main loop

    # some other code
    # check on exit
    if Again():
        continue
    else:
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

This can work!

```
class Cal:
    def main_menu(self):
        print ("I am in main menu")

    def again(self):
        x = raw_input("Go back to main menu(Y/N)")
        if x == 'y':
            self.main_menu()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    c = Cal()
    c.again()
```

When you will enter `y` it will go to the main menu.
Also, continue and break will not work here as they both are applied in loops.
You can use `raw_input` instead of `input` as `input` does not accept `string` values.